# Connect Java To PhpMyAdmin Demo Server?

Tags: java, jdbc, phpmyadmin

How Can I Connect Java Using the Jdbc Sql Driver To Connect To The  DEMO SERVER PHPMYADMIN (MYSQL) SERVER

http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/  77.78.110.71

I Can Connect to my local phpmyadmin server but not over the internet . I also have a bluehost phpmyadmin server but it also gives the same error

the problem is how i make the url

```
 String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/iftekhar";
```

//this works

```
 String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://77.78.110.71:3306/Iftekhar";
```

//this does not .. Yes i made a Db(Iftekhar) over there first

Comment: Just to be precise with terms, phpMyAdmin is a client program that accesses a mySQL server. There is no such thing as a "phpMyAdmin server"

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  You may have to set your host to allow remote connections if possible (some hosts do not allow it).

Answer (score 0):

Just few things:

1. have you tried to see if you can connect to 77.78.110.71 on port 3306? May be you just have a network problem.
2. the name of database in second case is capitalized, is it correct?
3. if 77.78.110.71 is the server where is running pypmyadmin, this does not means that mysql server is running on the same server.